# I am using JAVA Spring Boot REST API and Hibernate/JPA issue is with table name when the name I need to access contains a dot in the name like FOO.BAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

The problem is when hibernate builds the query it ignores the dot and sets the prepared statement "from" to look like

"from foo_bar"  when it needs to actually be "foo.bar"  So even though it connects to the primary database fine it never finds the table.  This is a DB2 schema where it is Database->table.sub-table ( not a join but a naming convention the DBA's use).

I have tried adding the dot in the `@Table name` prop

A snippet example is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO.BAR")
public class SomeClassName {

}
```

I tried using the application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://server:port/dbname and modifying that. Any ideas? Do I need to create my own naming convention or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly confident that the first value would be considered the schema name.

Perhaps trying the following would work?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BAR" schema="FOO")
public class SomeClassName {

}
```